# CnosDB export schema without data

Tags: database, cnosdb

Coming from MySQL side, I know that we can dump the schema as follows:

1. for the whole database:

```
mysqldump -u user -h localhost --no-data -p database > database.sql
```

2. for individual table:

```
mysqldump -u user -h localhost --no-data -p database tablename > table.sql
```

How could I dump the CnosDB schema in a similar way? I mean, only the measurements, tags, fields, no data included. Any arguments I am missing here in the [doc](https://cnosdb.github.io/docs/content/cnosdb/latest/managerment/export_import.html)?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need the sql-cmd "DESCRIBE DATABASE/TABLE dbname/tablename;".

Comment: This is indeed an indirect way.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem too, seems that CnosDB doesn't support getting the *create object* statement now.

I'm using `describe <obj_type> <obj_name>` statement to get a schema about that object. For examble now I have a table that named `table_a`:

```
 CREATE TABLE table_a (
  col_a double,
  col_b double,
  TAGS(tag_a, tag_b)
);
```

And describe the **table** `table_a`.

describe table `table_a`;

| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | COLUMN_TYPE | COMPRESSION_CODEC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| time | TIMESTAMP | TIME | DEFAULT |
| tag_a | STRING | TAG | DEFAULT |
| tag_b | STRING | TAG | DEFAULT |
| col_a | DOUBLE | FIELD | DEFAULT |
| col_b | DOUBLE | FIELD | DEFAULT |

---

I think it's easy to use the REST query API to get the result of table schema, and convert the table schema into a *create table* statement. Why don't they add this feature?